# How do I set my app up for production?

Tags: production, dev-to-production, mern

So, I guess this is less "programming" related but still relevant. I'm curious. How do companies set their apps up for production? Say I have a MERN app with an additional backend that actually supports my API. Can I push the server into production (where the actual API lives), and then push out the MERN app as well?

Node/Express server that has all of my API's functionality. (Users, Posts, etc)

MERN app that has a very minimal server (think, Express generated, kind of), but has my complete frontend.

Or do I just push the entire thing into production? The entire API, the entire frontend, and a little extra server side code to run the frontend.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It's depends, how your MERN system is designed? you are using boilerplate? it's all about configuration. what I did in http://harmony-boilerplate.com is to create development and production configuration. for example the client can point on different API (depend on your configuration) and you can choose whether to use only the server as standalone API or not.

Comment: Thanks! I talked to another developer and I kind of worked it out in my mind. I think having a backend/API only server in addition to the minimal server & frontend is a good setup. I think it's more scalable that way. (I can scale the API and not unnecessarily scale the frontend.)